# Icon representing juniors, age 7-15

Tags: icon, symbols, symbolism

I am trying to find an icon suitable to represent kids between the the age of 7 ~ 15.

So far I have come across this:

1) [image]

2) [image]

I was wondering if there is a better option out there?

Comment: Maybe add these details in your questions: what is the context in which you want to use this icon, and how big will it used at (average)? The rattle is a bit too "baby" for that age but something related to school is often used in that bracket of age. Second one is good, and if you need a feminine silhouette maybe add one with ponytails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion. Forget the option 1. It is for toddlers.

I thought Junior as a son that have the same name as the father. Posible terms, kid, minor, child, under 15...

For the icon, probably a head with **a cap**. I think that is representative of that range of age. (And maybe not pointing forward, but lateral or backwards)

https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=kid+cap+cartoon

Comment: I like your thought, kid with cap and a big smile.. :) nice one...

Comment: agreement on #1 - that is a toddler, and if i was between 7-15 i would find that rather offensive :)

Answer (score 0):

Kids playing, like kid with bat or ball or sketch pencil can also be an option.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the second I'm getting only male kids into my mind. I think you mean both male and female.

Try something which reflect both male and female kids, If you intended that one.

What others said are good and from my side I suggest something like **kids foot print** or some cartoon kind of kid shoes. They represent very well I guess.